# Transforming a code from tradingview to Tryd

Tags: groovy, pine-script

i have a code on tradingview(pine) that i would like to change to other plataform but dont know how to code, can you guy help me?

The other platform is called Tryd which uses GROOVY language

So is transform form Pine to Groovy

Comment: Do not expect other people to do your work; instead ask specific questions on concrete problems.

Comment: i could pay for it, i have no idea in programming, so if no one could hepl i would like to know is someone can do it and how much would cost to know if is worth it

Comment: Never heard of pine, but reading through the docs, the place you're going to have difficulty is with the built in functions it provides (such as `cci`) which if tryd doesn't have, you're going to have to rewrite in groovy.  That being said, Stackoverflow is a site for getting answers to specific issues with programming, not a broader _"write this code for me"_ site. There are [sites that do this sort of thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28129/is-there-a-good-site-to-hire-programmers-for-little-projects) but I've never used any, so can't recommend any